# How to paste a username into a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to paste a text box content from Sheet1 into the last row of column "B" in Sheet9. I have no problem inserting the text box content (a string) from a text box in Sheet1 into the last row in Sheet9 column "B" by using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. However, I find it difficult to add the username to the last row in Column "C", adjacent to the last row in column "B" in Sheet9.

Here I am copying the text box content from Sheet1 to the last row in column "B" in Sheet9, and trying to put the username in the last row in column "C" in Sheet 9.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    With Sheet9
        If KeyCode = 13 Then
            If TextBox1 <> vbNullString Then
                .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)(2, 1) = TextBox1
                .Cells(.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp)(2, 1)= Environ("username")
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I've revised the question quite a bit, but one thing is still unclear: what username are you referring to? The Windows account that the user is logged in with? Or do they type in some username in the same UserForm that they enter a string into TextBox1 on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to insert the UserName in column C in the row which should be the first empty row in column B, all you need is to place the UserName in column C first and then insert the TextBox value in column B.

Please give this a try...

```
.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Offset(0, 1) = Environ("UserName")
.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2) = Textbox1
```

Comment: Row should also be offset, otherwise it might only overwrite the last row.

Comment: @BrownishMonster Thanks for the pointing that out. I have edited the solution. :)

Comment: I find this function useful:        Public Function UserName()
    UserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function  ... You then can put this function in the cell as a formula =Username()

Comment: You're welcome Tom! Glad it worked as desired. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.